# What is the equivalent of PACKET_MMAP for kernel 4.x

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap, libpcap

Guys,
  We upgraded from 2.6 to 4.9 recently, lots of new stuff to catch up with.
  Anyway, we found the libpcap is obviously slower than previous version running on 2.6, first thing I am thinking about is enabling memory map at kernel building stage (PACKET_MMAP=true). But seems PACKET_MMAP is not supported at 4.x anymore, I am wondering any guru can help me with following questions:
1) how does 4.x enable the memory map?
2) any suggestions to tune up speed of libpcap running on 4.x kernel?

Many appreciation,
Tao

Comment: Now I can comment and make some follow-up questions. First, what is it you're upgrading? Some kind of embedded device under your control? If so, did you check the flag I mentioned in my answer? Note you'll probably need to also rebuild libpcap.

Comment: Also, what's exactly slower? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you want immediate mode but never set it? In that case, TPACKET_V3 may backfire in the sense that it buffers, in a way, packets and returns bigger blocks to userspace.

Comment: (Now just transcribing my previous comment to delete the answer)
PACKET_MMAP is still supported, as mentioned by user12812443, but you may need to set the `CONFIG_PACKET` flag, as the original config option was removed, probably because now all `AF_PACKET`-enabled builds ship `mmap` support.

Answer (score 0):

> But seems PACKET_MMAP is not supported at 4.x anymore

No, it's still supported.

> how does 4.x enable the memory map?

By being 4.x. :-)  It's *always* enabled in 3.0 and later kernels; there's no configuration option required (or available).

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion of speeding up libpcap?